# How to Convert .gis(geographic information system) file to .img format using C++?

Tags: c++, gis

I want convert .gis(geographic information system) file into .img format. Is this possible in C++? Can any one help me how to do this in C++????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would have to read the .gis file, decipher what it means and redraw that in a manner to your liking.

Check [GIS file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIS_file_formats) and check how they are stored.

Read that into your program.

Then use a graphics API (SDL/Allegro/OpenGL) and draw the verticies/lines/polygons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there any sample code with you? i am new to gis, i need to read .gis file into my program and convert it into .img format.

Comment: Check out [This site](http://www.scottsdaleaz.gov/maps/sampledata).  It has some sample data that you can play around with.  From what I can tell, there are a ton of standards for .gis files.  It may depend specifically on what format you are looking to mess with.  
Some of the standard file types also format very easily to .img files because they are stored in a similar fashion.